# NTILE(8) Function not creating 8 Groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a unique dataset where based on a value I need to separate the top 20% of the records from the bottom 80%.

So I created a flag that does this using `percentile_cont`.

Then I need to create randomized `row_number` for each individual row for top 20% and bottom 80%

So each row number column starts from 1 and doesn't count the rows where it's not the right percentage cohort.

Then I took these row numbers and broke them up in the proper amount of evenly sized categories for the top 20%, and top 80% using NTILE.

However, for some reason the NTILE(8) is not creating 8 groups. For the Top 20%, it's just throwing everyone in either 7, 8.

Similar thing is happening for the bottom 80% cohort.

Here is the code. Any idea on why is this happening?

```
SELECT
    *
    , CASE 
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number) = 1) THEN 'Top 20% Group1' 
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number) = 2) THEN 'Top 20% Group2'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number) = 3) THEN 'Top 20% Group3'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number) = 4) THEN 'Top 20% Group4'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number) = 5) THEN 'Top 20% Group5' 
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number) = 6) THEN 'Top 20% Group6'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number) = 7) THEN 'Top 20% Group7'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number) = 8) THEN 'Top 20% Group8'
        --Bottom 80%
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY bottom_80_random_row_number) = 1) THEN 'Bottom 80% Group1'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY bottom_80_random_row_number) = 2) THEN 'Bottom 80% Group2'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY bottom_80_random_row_number) = 3) THEN 'Bottom 80% Group3'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY bottom_80_random_row_number) = 4) THEN 'Bottom 80% Group4'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY bottom_80_random_row_number) = 5) THEN 'Bottom 80% Group5'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY bottom_80_random_row_number) = 6) THEN 'Bottom 80% Group6'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY bottom_80_random_row_number) = 7) THEN 'Bottom 80% Group7'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 AND NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY bottom_80_random_row_number) = 8) THEN 'Bottom 80% Group8'
        WHEN (top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND bottom_80_random_row_number > 113221) THEN 'Holdout'       
      END as Treatments
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *
        , CASE WHEN top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY NEWID()) 
                END AS top_20_random_row_number
        , CASE WHEN top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY NEWID())
                END AS bottom_80_random_row_number 
    FROM(
        SELECT
            c.id
            , c.name
            , score
            , CASE WHEN score >= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.80) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY score) OVER () THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS top_20_percentile_prospects_fl
        FROM Database.dbo.table c
        INNER JOIN #temp as l ON l.id = c.id        
    )base_code
) base_code2
```

Thanks!

I noticed that when I added this to the bottom of the query, the top 20% NTILE worked correctly.

```
WHERE top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1
```

Could someone explain to why that is? My guess is that it pertains to the row numbers somehow.

Comment: `top_20_random_row_number` has a large amount of nulls, 80% off it in fact. Looks like you need `PARTITION BY top_20_percentile_prospects_fl` in the `OVER` clause. Aside: feels like there are much faster ways to do this, I hope performance isn't an issue here

Comment: @Charlieface, Thanks I'll try it out and let you know how it goes. To be honest, this is my first time creating randomized groups in SQL. If you know of a function that could shorten this code, let me know please. Performance isn't too bad because its only 311k rows though.

Comment: @Charlieface, Adding the partition to each NTILE Function seemed to work for the top 20% but adding it to the bottom 80% only created 4 groups. I'm guessing it's still some NULLS being put into groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your issue is that the `NTILE` function is being calculated over all the rows. But you have pre-calculated the partitions via `top_20_percentile_prospects_fl`. So if you want `NTILE` over different groups, you need to partition the `NTILE` by that.

So for the top 20, you need a clause:
`PARTITION BY top_20_percentile_prospects_fl`.

But for the bottom 20, you need:
`PARTITON BY top_20_percentile_prospects_fl, CASE WHEN bottom_80_random_row_number <= 113221 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`
in order to get correct results.

---

To be honest, **this is not how one normally does window aggregates.**

Normally, you would partition your rows first with a calculated column, then `NTILE` over that. So:

```sql
SELECT
    *
    ,  CASE WHEN top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 THEN 'Top 20% '
       ELSE 'Bottom 80% ' END AS Part
    ,  CASE WHEN top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 AND rn > 113221
           THEN 'Holdout'       
       ELSE
           CASE NTile
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Group1'
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Group2'
           WHEN 3 THEN 'Group3'
           WHEN 4 THEN 'Group4'
           WHEN 5 THEN 'Group5'
           WHEN 6 THEN 'Group6'
           WHEN 7 THEN 'Group7'
           WHEN 8 THEN 'Group8'
           END
       END AS GroupNum
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    NTILE(8) OVER (PARTITION BY
        CASE 
          WHEN top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 0 THEN 0
          WHEN top_20_percentile_prospects_fl = 1 AND rn <= 113221 THEN 1
          ELSE 2 END
        ORDER BY top_20_random_row_number
      ) AS NTile
   FROM
   (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY top_20_percentile_prospects_fl ORDER BY NEWID()) AS random_row_number
    FROM(
        SELECT
            c.id
            , c.name
            , score
            , CASE WHEN score >= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.80) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY score) OVER () THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS top_20_percentile_prospects_fl
        FROM Database.dbo.table c
        INNER JOIN #temp as l ON l.id = c.id        
    )base_codeCentile
  ) base_codeRn
) base_codeNTile
```

**The big difference here** is that the `NTILE` results are now spread over multiple rows, rather than bodged together on the same rows (which you then need to separate with `CASE`)

Comment: Thank you! I sometimes have this habit of over complicating stuff but this is really helpful. Took me a while understand why It works but I got it. I have one question though. For the Bottom 80%, it still doesn't have all the groups. I think this is because the NTILE is probably calculating over the holdout still for that category

Comment: Sorry mistype should have been `ELSE 2` in the `NTILE` grouping i.e. you actually have 3 groups